# Calling and handling stored procedures which returns multiple resultsets in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6, multiple-resultsets

This is the department table which contains information about department

```
    Dept_Id
    Dept_Name
    Dept_Desc
```

This is the `employees` table which contains information about employees.

```
    Emp_Id
    Emp_Name
    Emp_Desc
    Emp_Salary
```

Stored procedure that returns multiple resultsets, both resultsets can not be mapped to any existing dto:

```
    Create procedure MyProcedure 
        (@DId int)
    As
    Begin 
        Select 
            Dept_Id, Dept_name, dept_desc, 
            count (e.Emp_Id) as ‘TotalEmpInDepartmentNo’
        From 
            departments d
        Join 
            Employees e On d.dept_id = e.dept_id
        Where 
            d.dept_id = @DId

        Select * 
        from products 
        Where dept_id = @dept_id
    End
    go
```

Complex dto which contains information regarding a category .

```
    public int Dept_Id { get; set; }
    public string Dept_Name{ get; set; }
    public string Dept_Desc{ get; set; }

    public int Count { get; set; }
    // Count represents total no of employees in each dept

    public IEmployeeDTO IList<IEmployeeDTO> EmployeesList { get; set; }
    //list represents employees list corresponding to the particular department
```

Employees dto which contains information about a particular employee

```
    public int Emp_Id{ get; set; }
    public string Emp_Name{ get; set; }
    public string Emp_Desc{ get; set; }
    public string Emp_Salary{ get; set;}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xxhy8.jpg)

First result sets contains a single row which contains information about a department

```
department id 
name 
desc
count --> total no of employees in this dept
```

Second resultset contains multiple rows of employees belong to that particular dept.

I want to call the procedure through Entity Framework code.

I want to do 2 things inside using :

1. Now I want to map the first result set to the starting four properties of complexDTO using entityConverter
2. I will create a separate employeeDTO for each row in second resultset , and after converting that DTO from entityconverter , I will add that EmployeeDTo to the list .